# Cardboard box for a cockatiel

Tags: cage, cockatiels

Does it make sense to hang the bottom of a cardboard box in a cage for a cockatiel?

I am thinking of cutting the bottom of small cardboard box, or half-gallon milk carton. The idea is to make a tray shape, attach it to the side of the cage with twist-ties. As a resting/nesting place.

Would a cockatiel like this?

Is cardboard safe?

Comment: My first question would be: how long do you expect cardboard to last? Sounds more like something to take apart than to rest in ;)

Comment: If you want it as a nest, i'd go for something more solid, it would be more secure than cardboard

Answer (score 4):

### Should I use cardboard?

> Does it make sense to hang the bottom of a cardboard box in a cage for a cockatiel?

Birds LOVE boxes, this is a great idea!

> Is cardboard safe?

Cardboard is very safe, I make many toys with cardboard boxes (cereal boxes, cookie boxes etc.) - they tend to make very good foraging opportunities.

### When to not use boxes

Some birds can get very defensive with boxes as it they can claim it like a nest - this nesting behavior can trigger egg laying in our females. Chronic egg laying is problematic to their health as it depletes nutrients from their bodies which can result in:

- [Egg binding](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/egg-binding-in-birds)
- Osteoporosis
- Feather loss
- Poor feather growth

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer. We have African Grays ; they love to spend most of the day shredding flat cardboard.  We put a small box in the females cage, she soon stated laying eggs which involved screaming so we removed the box.